# How to share MP3 file + text in Android?

Tags: java, android

I have tried to make a code for sharing an MP3 file and text at once on Button click, but in reality when I click the share button and choose for example WhatsApp I can only share the MP3 file but not the text with the MP3 at once. Here is the code that I am using to share this both files:

```
                    btn_share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            String sharePath = OUTPUT_PATH+"temp/output/out.mp3";
                            Uri uri = Uri.parse(sharePath);
                            Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                            share.setType("*/*");
                            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
                            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Get more info about our band");
                            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share your sound"));
                        }
                    });
```

Is it not possible or is WhatsApp just blocking such actions? Do you know a solution to fix it? Thanks in advance for helping me!